# Search NSString and show result with ellipsis

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to search a string for a search term and highlight all occurrences in the string.

Some text around the search term should be displayed (between ...) and the search term should be in bold font style (NSMutableAttributedString).

sample: search for "text"

> ...sample **text** bla... ...more **text** blabla... ...bla **text** blabla...

```
NSString *haystackString = [[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stripHTML];
NSString *needleString = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text;
if (!self.searchRegex) {
    self.searchRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(?:\\S+\\s)?\\S*%@\\S*(?:\\s\\S+)?", needleString] options:(NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators + NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive) error:nil];
}
NSArray *matches = [self.searchRegex matchesInString:haystackString options:kNilOptions range:NSMakeRange(0, haystackString.length)];
NSMutableString *tempString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    [tempString appendString:@"..."];
    [tempString appendString:[haystackString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:0]]];
    [tempString appendString:@"..."];
}
if (tempString) {
    cell.textLabel.text = tempString;
}
```

My current code seems to be slow and doesn't support NSMutableAttributedString yet. Is there a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a scanner instead of a regex?

Comment: I've heared that NSScanner should be faster, but I don't know how this would is done with the wanted output like in the upper post: {dots}{word ahead}{space}{searchterm bold in word}{space}{word after}{dots}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use an attributedString just change your code like this

```
// Create a reusable attributed string dots and matchStyle dictionary
NSAttributedString *dots = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"..."];
NSDictionary *matchStyle = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]};

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
{
    NSString *matchString = [haystackString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:0]];

    [attributedText appendAttributedString:dots];
    [attributedText appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:matchString attributes:matchStyle]];
    [attributedText appendAttributedString:dots];
}

if (attributedText.length > 0)
{
    cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedText;
}
```

Best,
Sascha

Comment: Thanks a alot. I've changed my code accordingly, also found a bug in the regex (provided only match at range 0) and it's now displayed nicely. [link](http://pastebin.com/uPqFrxk8). But still the speed problem exists (code is used in configureCell and it stutters). The Documents app (Raeddle) does this very smoothly. Do you have an idea concerning speed improvement?

Answer (score 0):

`NSScanner` can be used as an alternative to a regular expression to find the location of your text. Once you have the location of a match you can extract the section before and after and build your result string.

Using either technique, you should process the string and build the result set before trying to display the result in a table. This ensures no real processing is done while scrolling.

If you can't do it before, run it on a background thread and push the result back to the main thread to update the cell (if it's still visible, so use the index path to check).